# What would happen if we deploy into production when the org is still working

Tags: deployment

We have a urgent bug fix which needs to be deployed into prod. However, the prod is still functioning at this point. So what would happen if we deploy into prod when someone is using the related trigger/apex class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So what would happen if we deploy into prod when someone is using the related trigger/apex class?

"Nothing."

Transactions already in progress will use the old code, and once deployed, transactions afterwards will use the new code. At no point will users get an error message because the system is "compiling" or something like that.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you deploy a new version of a Visualforce page or its Apex controller, then anyone currently using that page will get an error message the next time they do something that would trigger an AJAX request to the controller. So it's good practice to send out a pre- and post-deployment notice to affected users so they aren't hit by surprise.